# Oracle 18C X64 on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Before describing the issue, please let me just say that I am new to Oracle as I am a microsoft developer.

I am trying since 3 days to install an oracle database on my windows machine running windows 7 64bit enterprise and then using "SQL developer" to manage and query local databases. AT latesr stage maybe I will get Toad.

Every time that I install the software everything is working fine; I can open the https://localhost:5500/em/ website, I can open the defalt created database with SQL developer and using Oracle database configutaion assistant to check the database created configuration. 
After restarting my machine I can see that the database is running, [image: SqlPlus query] , All services are still up and running;

[image: Oracle Services]

But I am unable to browse https://localhost:5500/em/ website and to connect to the "orcl" database with SQL developer as I just did successfully before restarting my machine. When I try I get this error: `IO Error: Socket read interrupted`

[image]

Is now 3 days that I am trying everything and just for more info, below my environment path variables and a screenshot of the oracle home reg key

Path:       `C:\Oracle\ORA18_X64_FILES\bin;C:\Oracle\InstantClient;C:\Oracle\OdbcDrivers;`

TNS_ADMIN   `C:\Oracle\ORA18_X64_FILES\network\admin`

[image: KEY_OraDB18Home1]

Can anyone suggest what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution; the problem with Sql Developer was that the oracle database listener.ora file had the "Listener Parameter File" value pointing to the wrong location:

**previous and wrong value:** 
Listener Parameter File   *C:\Oracle\OdbcDrivers\listener.ora*

**Correct value**
Listener Parameter File ***C:\Oracle\ORA18_X64_FILES\network\admin***

as for the EM express website, the issue was that the sqlnet.ora file had **this line** *SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)*
which has now been **changed to** *SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)*